# SQL - Listing just the table name side by side and number of blocks below the respective tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

I'm very new with SQL and would need help.

I have the follow relational tables Address, Customer and order.

1) How can I list the table names in column rather than in rows like below?

2) How can the number of blocks be listed respectively below the tables?

3) I do not have a ALL table but how can I display the 'ALL' column with the total number of blocks below it.

```
Address         Customer         Order            All
-------         -------          -------          -------
total-blocks    total-blocks     total-blocks     total-blocks
```

Comment: You've tagged both mysql and oracle as your platform.  The answer to this question is probably different for each platform.  Please remove one or the other so that a more specific answer can be given.

Comment: Ok! thanks for the tips.. removed